# PHP CLI: read from stdin but with a timeout

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin

I have a command line PHP script with a loop where at the end of each loop I want to have an option to terminate the script gracefully. Is there a way where I can either...

**a)** prompt the user for input at the end of each loop (eg. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042626/php-read-from-socket-or-stdin)) but have a timeout so the script continues after a while if no input is received?

or

**b)** at the end of each loop have it check if any input has been received since the previous iteration?

Comment: Probably not as PHP is not (normally) ran in an asynchronous way.  Maybe with websockets you could do something like this, PHP is built around the request/response structure of HTTP, so there is not really a way to interact with it during the response phase of things,  ie, there is  no 2-way communication.